# Smart Card(Sim Card), connect to stm32 via USART(UART)

Tags: stm32, embed, uart, sim-card, usart

After getting ATR and sending PTS, I tried to send APDU, but response is always the same as APDU which has been sent.
I tried to change the frequency for USART(Clock) and Baud Rate, after I tried to change PTS value for ETU and T=0, but got always the same result.
[STM32](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qyP87.png)